# Change default Task Type to 'Fixed Work' in Microsoft Project 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

When I create a new task in Microsoft Project it defaults to "Fixed Units", however most of the projects we do are estimated upfront so we need to schedule based on fixed amount of effort but variable amount of resources, i.e. we can add more resources to meet a deadline.

At the moment, I have to go in and change the tasks to be "Fixed Work" by selecting all tasks and editing them in the Advanced menu.

Is there a way this can be set as the default?

Thanks
Marko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  **File > Options, Schedule category**.  Select "All New Projects" and set the default task type as needed.  You can also edit multiple tasks by selecting them and using the Information button on the Task Ribbon or you may add the type field to a task table and fill down.